# Преобразование типов в C#

Tags: c#, типизация

Начинаю изучать C#. Решил написать простенький консольный конвертер. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает следующая строчка кода:

```
  double nCels = Convert.ToDouble ( (nFahr - 32)*(5/9));
  Console.WriteLine(nCels);
```

При любом значении `nFahr` возвращается 0

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
Console.WriteLine( (double)((nFahr - 32)*(5/9)) );
```

Называется "Явное преобразование", про преобразования и приведения типов можете почитать на [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173105)

Comment: `*(5/9)` почему-то упорно возвращает 0. А вот `/1.8` выдает правильный результат.

Comment: Ну так (5/9) это все равно, что int x = 5, int y = 9, (x/y)=0. Вот (5.0/9.0) даст правильный результат.

Comment: Olter, спасибо. Так действительно работает. Мне как-то в голову не пришло, что 5/9 даст целое число. Заодно прояснило почему 9/5 дает единицу.

Comment: потому что для `int` оператор `/` выполняет деление без остатка, чтобы получить `double`, как уже говорилось нужно добавить ноль или букву `d` - `5d/9d`

Comment: Так вот зачем эти буковки d, M...

Comment: `d - double`, `l - long`: указывает на *тип значения*